# Datatables ajax reload is ignoring dynamically updated request parameters

Tags: datatable, datatables, server-side

I am using server side jquery datatable 1.10.16.  I am want to reload the data by requesting the datatable ajax with updated parameters.
To reload the datatable I am using the below datatable api:

```
$('#user_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

My datatable initailization is given below:

```
$('#user_data').DataTable({
        // to hide search filter
        "searching": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 25, 50], [5, 25, 50]],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            "url": '/admin/getStats',
            "data": {user_id: user_id, date_range: JSON.stringify(DATE_RANGE)},

        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
            {data: 'country', name: 'country'}
        ]
    });
```

DATE_RANGE and user_id are global variables which are updated like this:

```
     $('#dateSelector').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                DATE_RANGE[0] = picker.startDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
                DATE_RANGE[1] = picker.endDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
                console.log(DATE_RANGE); // here I am getting updated value properly
// reloading the datatable , but the parameters are the previous one
                $('#user_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            });
```

How to pass updated parameters ?

Comment: Did you try disable the cache in datatables settings?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I have added "cache": false, to datatable on initialization but still old parameters are persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Disable caching for the table in the oSettings [this param is changing based on the DT version. Refer documentation of the version you are using.]
After calling

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

call this immediately:

```
table.ajax.clearAjaxParams();
```

Again this changes with version based. Refer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it somehow. In future people may need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fetchData();
});

function fetchData() {
$('#user_data').DataTable({
        // to hide search filter
        "searching": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 25, 50], [5, 25, 50]],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            "url": '/admin/getStats',
            "data": {user_id: user_id, date_range: JSON.stringify(DATE_RANGE)},

        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
            {data: 'country', name: 'country'}
        ]
    });
}

$('#dateSelector').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
.....
....

     $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
     fetchData();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just redraw the dataTable, a new post request with the updated parameters will be sent to the server.

```
$('#dateSelector').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $('#user_data').DataTable().draw();
}
```